# redirect to another page with slide effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a functionality in jquery-mobile in which I want to redirect to another page on click of an image after a delay. So far i have reached till here-

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "myPage.html";
},1000);
```

Its working fine but I want that the page should redirect with slide effect of jQuery mobile.
Doed anybody have any idea?

Comment: Uh... Not really redirecting, but maybe try an `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer guys..!!

I replaced window.location.href = "myPage.html" with

```
$.mobile.changePage("myPage.html",{transition:"slide"});
```

This is redirecting the page to the target page with slide effect!
Check it out [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)

Comment: This should be the selected answer!  Note, I had to use $.mobile.changePage(url, { transition: "slide", reverse: true }); to slide left instead of right.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting a page with window location reload is not possible. When you try to change a window location reload it will refresh the page.

So you can try something like

- loading your target content within an `iframe`
- or,  use ajax method to load content
- or, make a sliding effect with your previously loaded content

In order to load via ajax use can use any one methods like **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)** or **[`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax)**

For example:

You can use `.load()` like following:

```
$('#target_container').load('YOUR_URL', function() {
   // do something
});
```

OR can use `.ajax()` like following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'YOUR_URL'.
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(response) {
    $('#target_container').html(response);
  }
});
```

Read more about above methods and use what you like.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting  window.location.href  , Why dont you try this,

```
    $('#maindiv').load('mypage.html', function() {
       alert('Load was performed.');
      //  here slide the content and render the maindiv
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting a page like you did in your example code will make the page refresh and therefore an effect impossible. If you want to achieve something like a slidein page you might want to take a look at sliding in an iframe that holds the page that you want to redirect to (and maybe do the complete location refresh after the effect was finished).